# Cant loop cut after bevel one side

Tags: modeling, bevel

I am a Blender beginner and when trying to model super basic shapes I already run into problems:

I beveled one edge and now I cant do a loop cut on this side anymore:

[image]

On the other side it is working:
[image]

What did I do wrong? And how can I make it better? I read there should be no n-gons but this bevel always creates an n-gon.

Comment: A loop cut can only cut face loops in half. A face loop means faces continuing in a certain direction, tha's why it only works on quads. A quad always has to each edge two adjacent edges and an opposing edge. The loop cut goes from one chosen edge to the opposing edge. Since an n-gon has more than one edge opposite another, the loop cut cannot continue because it is not clear which edge to cut. What you can do in your case is select only the edges you want to cut and then right-click and choose _Subdivide_.

Comment: Makes sense but how to use the bevel tool so it doesnt create n-gons? Or how to clean it up? I tried the knife tool but it is hell of work...

Comment: Well, you cannot tell the Bevel tool to not create n-gons. How exactly should the quads or tris be created from the beveled edge? And as soon as you bevel another edge, maybe even with a different offset and a different number of segments this will start to become a real mess. But by the way, although there are cases where n-gons should be avoided, it's a "myth" that you should never have n-gons. There might be even cases where n-gons are better, for simpler and better to handle geometry. But like all things it has pros and cons.

Comment: What you could have done beforehand is first make the loop cut and then bevel the edge. Or afterwards you have to use _Subdivide_ on those edges that you need to cut or the _Knife_ tool with angle constraint to get a straight vertical cut.